# ASP.net Core (RC2): Get IP and Username

Tags: ip-address, asp.net-core-mvc

I found this [solution](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/dev/samples/HttpOverridesSample/Startup.cs#L13) to get remote IP address in ASP.Net Core RC2 (.Net Framework) Web Application. This works fine. It's possible to get Client user Name too (without Authentification)?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: What you mean under "user name"? User login on windows computer from which user visits you site? Then you need some kind of Authentication.

Comment: What type of authentication should I use if I want no user Management? I need the user logon only for logging purposes.

Comment: Authentication is not about user management, but about user identification. How you want user to "proof" you that his name is 'Alice'? Do you need user be in your windows domain or have Facebook account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dmitry eluded to, you can't get the client user name without authentication.

At a low level, the way that the remote IP address is accessed is via the http headers. It's sent in a header called REMOTE_ADDR.

So when you call `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` to get the client IP address what it's doing under the hood is returning the value from the REMOTE_ADDR header. But, there is no header value for the client user name of an unauthenticated user.